# R SVM, Reponse with 4 levels

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am new to ML, but am trying to run a SVM using the caret package.  I've tried to duplicate code that I've used on a tutorial, but am running into an issue.  My response has 4 levels (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) and in my train function I have

```
train(x=sftrainX,
              y= sftrainY,
              method = "svmRadial",   
              tuneLength = 9,                   
              preProc = c("center","scale"),  
              metric="ROC",
              trControl=trainControl(method="repeatedcv",   
                        repeats=5,          
                        summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,    
                        classProbs=TRUE))
```

But I'm getting an error...

```
Error in ctrl$summaryFunction(testOutput, lev, method) : 
Your outcome has 4 levels. The twoClassSummary() function isn't appropriate.
```

I cannot find anything in my research to replace the, "twoClassSummary()" with, so was hoping someone could help me in the right direction.

Data Background: There is no NA data, and I have 1088 observations with 12 variables for my predictors (sftrainX).

Comment: So you did read the official docs? ```defaultSummary``` (or probably just no explicit setting at all; but i'm not much of an R + caret user).

Comment: It runs without an explicit setting, but I wasn't sure if there wasn't something different.  The docs says how twoClassSummary is using the AUC  to find the best model which I know can be used in linear models.  I just don't know why it can't for more than 2 levels.